# too many levels of symbolic links /usr/bin/gcc in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

I'm somewhat new to Ubuntu so my debugging skills on this platform are very limited.  Anyway, to make a long story short I'm running into issues associated with gcc.  I ran into some errors with a tool I was using and by following a number of recommendations online I believe I made the problem worse. 
I have too many levels of symbolic links for /usr/bin/gcc as well as /usr/bin/gcc-4.7.

```
greg@greg-P170EM:~$ which gcc

greg@greg-P170EM:~$ 

greg@greg-P170EM:~$ which g++

/usr/bin/g++
```

As you can see I don't get the expected /usr/bin/gcc for the first command.

This issue is recognizable when installing software from the repository.  For example, when I tried to install Wine, I'll get the error shown below:

```
Setting up imagemagick (8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/bin/gcc': Too many levels of symbolic links
dpkg: error processing imagemagick (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do a `ls -l` on /usr/bin/gcc, then follow the links and count how many there are to the actual binary. Most likely there's a circular reference somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kevin.  Unfortunately, I've tried that and it results in the following error:                            greg@greg-P170EM:~$ ls -1 /usr/bin/gcc
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/gcc: Too many levels of symbolic links

Comment: @notarg: `-l` (letter ell) not `-1` (digit one).  Also depending on what you've messed up, you might need `/bin/ls -l /usr/bin/gcc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems likely that you've borked your gcc install somehow (by manually moving/removing files and symlinks?).  It may be possible to figure out exactly which wires are crossed and fix them, but the easiest way to fix things is likely by reinstalling the gcc package -- first do `sudo apt-get remove gcc`, and then `sudo apt-get install gcc`

Comment: Something was definitely borked.  I ended up removing the symbolic links and recreating them.  Multiple versions of gcc were installed and something got messed up along the way. I installed gcc-4.8 created a symbolic link to that version, and now things seem to be behaving.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone cares I was getting a too many levels of symbolic links when i had created a bad link. I had to remove it first and then run the link command again, which fixed my problem.